# If Column is ISNULL set alias to No Project

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a Stored Procedure to select the ProjectID and then automatically group by the ProjectID in an Obout grid. If the ProjectID ISNULL, then it should be Grouped under "No Project", which is the column name. My sql skills are rusty, help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    SELECT Media.ProjectID ((ProjectID+ISNULL("NO PROJECT")AS "No Project"))
FROM Media
```

Comment: It would probably help if you mention what database engine you're working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
SELECT ProjectID, 
    CASE WHEN ProjectID IS NULL THEN 'No Project' ELSE NULL END AS "No Project"
FROM Media
```

---

Without knowing exactly what you are trying to do, I might want to suggest something like this instead - this will get the project ID and a group name (not sure if you need the cast):

```
SELECT ProjectID, 
    CASE WHEN ProjectID IS NULL THEN 'No Project' 
         ELSE CAST(ProjectID AS VARCHAR(20)) END AS "Group"
FROM Media
```

Or, using the COALESCE operator (not sure your exact dialect):

```
SELECT ProjectID, COALESCE(CAST(ProjectID AS VARCHAR(20)), 'No Project') AS "Group"
FROM Media
```

Comment: SELECT 
    COALESCE(CAST(ProjectID as VARCHAR(20)), 'NO PROJECT') AS "No Project" 
FROM Media